# AssertionError ERR_ASSERTION: catch clause variable is not an Error instance

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

so what happens is i cant set up the authentication, firestore, and cloud storage in my project, it keeps showing this error,

`[error] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: catch clause variable is not an Error instance`

```
at assertIsError (C:\Users\PATH\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\utilities\error.js:19:26)
at AddCommandModule.runSchematic (C:\Users\PATH\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\schematics-command-module.js:266:43)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async AddCommandModule.executeSchematic (C:\Users\PATH\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\commands\add\cli.js:279:20)
at async AddCommandModule.handler (C:\Users\PATH\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-module.js:119:24)
```

This is whats in assert error

```
function assertIsError(value) {
    const isError = value instanceof Error ||
        // The following is needing to identify errors coming from RxJs.
        (typeof value === 'object' && value && 'name' in value && 'message' in value);
    (0, assert_1.default)(isError, 'catch clause variable is not an Error instance');
}
```

i dont know whats causing this but i have all my packages up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved at last!
i tried this

`npm install firebase-tools`

and tried setting up the fire features again and it worked

Comment: yes sorry, i just cant accept it within 22 hours